# Completar (Autocompletar?) campos desde modelo db Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, django-models

Estoy iniciando en Django y he estado buscando información acerca de completar campos en relación a una selección de otro campo ForeignKey. Por ejemplo, al rellenar un formulario, seleccionar un producto en un campo select y que esto actualice el valor en otro campo (para mostrarlo en el template y/o guardarlo).

Pensaba inicialmente que esto era algo común y por lo tanto habría mucha información y me doy cuenta que no es tan así, ya que veo en el foro hay varias preguntas sobre esto algunas sin respuestas y otra que hablan de django-autocomplete o django-smart-selects (quizás estoy buscando mal). 
¿Cual sería la mejor forma de lograr esto? 
Si hay alguien que me puede aportar un poco de luz sobre esto para buscar información en esa dirección. 
Gracias.

Comment: No te entiendo muy bien, pero para autocompletar un campo en base a otro en tiempo real, debes utilizar Javascript.

Comment: Gracias @Julio César parece que la palabra no sería autocompletar, la pregunta va orientada a que al elegir un campo foreignkey de un modelo que muestre otro campo del modelo en un campo input. Ponía el ejemplo de elegir un producto y que muestre el precio de ese producto. Otro ejemplo sería poner el rut o dni y que mostrará el nombre y apellido. Me explico?

Comment: Según entiendo, al seleccionar una opción en el select(relación) quieres que aparezca un input u otro campo, estoy en lo correcto verdad?. En dado caso se así, necesitas utilizar JavaScript.

Comment: Si, que aparezca un valor (de la bd) en un input. 
Ok, entonces habría trabajar esto con JavaScrip?

Comment: Podrias comentar algún ejemplo o algún link que tenga un ejemplo por favor?.

Comment: Pues no sabría darte un ejemplo, ya que no se mucho de JavaScript, pero para hacerlo tienes que utilizarlo.

Comment: Gracias @Julio Cesar buscando en esa dirección he encontrado mas información https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39189811/ 
Aun no logro hacerlo pero cada vez menos perdido :-)

Comment: Si, a lo mejor esa pregunta guía, sobretodo en como hacerlo con JavaScript.